# Making two items in cardview appear in one line

Tags: xml, firebase, responsive-design, android-cardview

i'm using firebase database to list items in recycler view, and i want two items to be on the same line like this:
[image]

but for me it's displaying like this
[image]
this is my cardview list layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="15dp"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_name"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Price"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@id/product_image"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Description"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/product_price"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

i want to make it so somehow instead of only one showing up in a line in recyclerview i want mutiple ones to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grid layout manager for ReccyclerView with 2 as second parameter, for showing 2 columns.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```